# C# - How to check if a specific part of ComboBox Dropdown Item is clicked

Tags: c#, visual-studio, drop-down-menu, combobox

I'm new to the C# part of programming, I am currently making a Program that is centered functionally around a ComboBox. In the Combobox, I have a concatenated string that looks like this:

IF checked

```
("☑ " + client.shortName)
```

IF unchecked

```
("☐ " + client.shortName)
```

So the output would be something like

```
☐ RealMadrid
```

As one item in the dropdown list of a comboBox.

My question is, can I implement an event handler that detects when the CheckBox (Not the actual Control Type, more like a character) region of the dropdown is clicked? If yes, Can I get a walk-through on how to do it? (It doesn't have to be a full class, but I would be grateful if It was)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you be able to use the SelectedIndexChanged event, then just check the first character of the selected value (string) for '☑' or '☐'?

Edit - I think I understand - you want the user to be able to select the item without changing the checkbox 'checked' property, but also allow them to change it if they click towards the left side of the item. You can check the location of the cursor in relation to the form location and determine which side of the combobox they are selecting. It is not necessarily a clean implementation, but I don't think there's another way to fool the program using controls like that.

Comment: That's a good idea, your edit I mean, I don't need the SelectedIndexChanged Event Handler. I guess that may be one of the only ways I could implement this.

Comment: You will still need some kind of event (maybe just Click), but then you will want to get the X location of the Form and compare it to the X location of the cursor to determine which side of the combobox item the user is selecting.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I am going to try and do, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason to be using a ComboBox as opposed to a number of Checkboxes where the text is updated with the client.shortName?

Comment: Yeah, a GroupBox with lots of items rely on which item in the ComboBox is selected, say it's Real Madrid, one of the text boxes in the group box would be updated to Sport: Soccer, or Broncos which would give Sport: Football.

Comment: Is the purpose to be able to 'check' more than one item within the ComboBox?

Comment: Yeah that's what I want to be able to do

Comment: Perhaps a ListBox with SelectionMode set to Multi would suit your needs better? As bstiffler582 mentioned, using a ComboBox doesn't necessarily seem the cleanest way to go about this.

And If his assumption is true, you wont necessarily need the  '☑' or '☐', but just the fact that they're selected should be enough.

Comment: I can't use a list box since the whole idea of this is program is simplicity and portability, unless there is a way to add ListBox as the dropdown of ComboBox, this won't be what I need.